# PowerShell - Copy specific lines from multiple specific nested files

Tags: powershell

So, the folder structure looks like this:

RootFolder

- RootFolder

  - SubFolder1

    - SubSubFolder1

      - totals.txt
    - SubSubFolder2

      - totals.txt
  - SubFolder2

    - SubSubFolder1

      - totals.txt
    - SubSubFolder2

      - totals.txt

What I want to do is recursively walk through these Subfolders for the totals.txt file. Read content, and copy lines 22,26,30,34,38,and 42 (with first line being 0 not 1)into a single combined file.

I started with this code:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -like "totals.txt" } | Get-Content | Select-Object -Index 22,26,30,34,38,42  | Add-Content "DataInportFile.txt"
```

However this only finds RootFolder\SubFolder\SubSubFolder\totals.txt and then exits script. Not what I'm looking for...

What I need is the above script to continue searching recursively for the next file and next until all directories have been searched in structure. So I used this:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | ForEach-Object {$_ -like "totals.txt" } | Get-Content | Select-Object -Index 22,26,30,34,38,42  | Add-Content "DataInportFile.txt"
```

However, this script errors

```
C:\Users\user1\scripts\Untitled1.ps1:1 char:69
+ ... urse | ForEach-Object {$_ -like "totals.txt" } | $_.filename #| Get- ...
+                                                       ~~~~~~~~~~~
Expressions are only allowed as the first element of a pipeline.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ExpressionsMustBeFirstInPipeline
```

I could use some help figuring out the rest of this powershell script. So close but no joy. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1):

Realized I needed to walk through the array

For other's reference, this code works as required:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse | Where-Object {$_ -like "totals.txt" } | 
    %{
        (Get-Content $_.FullName) | Select-Object -Index 22,26,30,34,38,42  | Add-Content "DataInportFile.txt"
        }
```

Comment: `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter "totals.txt" |` without the where is more efficient.